# mpool_malloc error, cannot access shell

Tags: ubuntu, clamav

I'm getting spammed the following error on boot:

LibClamAC Error: mpool_malloc(): Attempt to allocate 8388608 bytes. Please report to http://bugs.clamav.net

I read that I will need to update... but the problem is this is happening on boot and I keep getting spammed by this error and fills the screen and I can't access the shell.

Anyone know how I can access the shell to update his?

I'm running ubuntu 12.04

Pic of error
https://i.imgur.com/WFJO2q0.jpg

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you have physical access first try logging in on an alternate console. Alternate consoles can be accessed using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd> for n in say 1 to 4.

If the above doesn't help I would try [booting to single user mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132965/how-do-i-boot-into-single-user-mode-from-grub) and the use that to dsable the clamav startup. Reboot back too multi-user and then update clamav.